# WordPress blog post limitation not working

Tags: wordpress

I set 9 posts per page php query but its not working. I am using custom themes. And when I change theme its working fine. How to solve blog post per page 5 items?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ftci.png)

Comment: Please provide blog page listing code, so we can help you?

Comment: @Romna, Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code for display blog post listing with paginations:

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10
));

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php // post content goes here ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php my_pagination(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

        <?php // no posts found message goes here ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this works for you.